# Select one record with a given status from a set of duplicate records with at least this one status

Tags: sql, sqlite

I have a system that requests information by sending 3 parameters to an external system: user, start_date and end_date.

I have a table

```
request (
  id, 
  user, 
  start_date, 
  end_date, 
  status
)
```

that logs these requests and their status (`Done` for the requests that have returned, `Waiting` for the requests that havent yet returned).

Every few hours I will resubmit the requests that havent yet returned, even though the initial request could still return some time in the future.

After some time, my table will have multiple requests for the same user/start_date/end_date, some of them Waiting, some Done.

What I need is a query that returns a list of ids of all duplicate requests with the exception of 1 Done, where at least one request has status=Done.

In summary, I need a way to clear the exceeding requests for a given user/start_date/end_date, if at least one of them has status=Done (doesnt matter which one, I just need to keep 1 status = Done for a given user/start_date/end_date).

So far I've been able to pinpoint the duplicate requests that have at least 1 Done. To select all but one complete from this query, I would most likely wrap this entire query into 2 more selects and do the magic, but the query as is, is already really slow. Can someone help me refactor it and select the end result i need?

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!5/10c25a/1

I'm using SQLite

The expected result from the dataset provided in the sqlfiddle is this:

`454, 457, 603, (604 or 605 not both), 607, 608`

Comment: Is it safe to assume that the `Done` request with the lowest `id` is the one to keep?

Comment: Is it possible to have an earlier request with `Status` of "Waiting" and a later duplicate with `Status` "Done"?

Comment: Urgh, why do you have duplicate `id` values?

Comment: Sample data and desired results would really help.

Comment: Phil its not safe to assume anything about the order of the status of the requests and yes, its possible to have that setup of statuses. I also fixed the duplicate ids.

GordonLinoff I just added the expected result to the question and sample data to sqlfiddle

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
select r.id from request r inner join (
    select user, start_date, end_date,
        min(case when status = 'Done' then id end) as keep_id
    from request
    group by user, start_date, end_date
    having count(case when status = 'Done' then 1 end) > 0 and count(*) > 1
) s on  s.user = r.user and s.start_date = r.start_date and s.end_date = r.end_date
    and s.keep_id <> r.id
```

Comment: Very nice use  of case expressions but the simplicity of Phil's answer is just astonishing

Comment: It's cool. They're essentially the same. I went the desired table route since that's what you were already doing and correlated queries seem to confuse a lot of people.

Comment: After further consideration, I decided to choose your solution as the accepted one. I ran both queries on a much larger dataset (20k records) and your solution took only 25ms while Phil's took almost 10s.

Comment: Thanks. Glad it worked out. Of course that was supposed to be "derived tables" earlier.

Comment: Yikes, that's a massive difference. Can't really see anything obvious that would cause that though. Would need to dig into the execution plans of each query

Answer (score 1):

What you're after are records that match this criteria...

- There exists another record with `Status` "Done"
- That other "Done" record matches `user`, `start_date` and `end_date`
- That other record has a lower `id` value (because you need *something* to identify the record to *keep*) **or** the other record has a higher `id` but the record you're looking at has `Status` "Waiting"

With all that in mind, here's your query

```
SELECT id FROM request r1
WHERE EXISTS (
  SELECT 1 FROM request r2
  WHERE r2.Status = 'Done'
  AND r1.user = r2.user
  AND r1.start_date = r2.start_date
  AND r1.end_date = r2.end_date
  AND (r1.id > r2.id OR r1.Status = 'Waiting')
)
ORDER BY id
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!5/10c25a/26 ~ produces IDs 454, 457, 603, 605, 607 and 608